# UILabel wont fill two lines if needed

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a UILabel in a collection view cell that is center aligned with number of lines = 0 and line breaks = word wrap

My text is dynamic, dependent upon requested data, so some cell's don't need two lines. 
Any idea why it still wont go to the second line if needed? Getting stuck on this.

Comment: You're going to have to post some code.

Comment: What result are you seeing? Is the text truncated with an ellipsis, or does it just run of the right edge of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know because I do not see any code, I suggest looking at the size of the label. Are you sure the label is not getting stretched / set to a size larger then the collectionviewcell?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're experiencing:

I made two labels, each with:

- number of lines = 0
- word wrap activated
- just enough x and y constraints to keep them in place on the view!

[image: lots of text running off the screen]

I think this is what you want:

I added constraints to each label making their width less than or equal to 300

[image: wrap the words]